# Index was out of range on an ADOQuery - Very Random

Tags: delphi, adoconnection, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index` randomly emailed through to me on my website. I cannot reproduce this error either by force or general testing and it is somewhat confusing.

From what I can see in the stack trace, it happens randomly when opening a dataset and trying to get a value. The stack trace showed I got the error when calling this function:

```
function TDB.FGetLastInsertID: Integer;
const
  selSQL = 'select scope_identity() as LastID';
var
  selCursor: TDataSet;
begin
  selCursor := Cursor(selSQL); //Returns a DataSet from a TADOQuery
  try
     Result := selCursor.FieldByName('LASTID').AsInteger;
  finally
     selCursor.Close;
     selCursor.Free;
  end;
end;
```

As I said, I cannot get this to reproduce the error and it seems to happen randomly on any query I run. I have tried closing the connection, setting it to inactive ect to reproduce the error but cannot.

Has anyone got any ideas?

EDIT: It seems its the close causing issues after examining the stack trace more closely:

```
Stack Trace: at 
System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index) at 
Borland.Vcl.TList.Delete(Int32 Index) at Borland.Vcl.TList.Remove(Object Item) at 
Borland.Vcl.TDBBufferList.FreeHGlobal(IntPtr Ptr) at 
Borland.Vcl.TCustomADODataSet.FreeRecordBuffer(IntPtr& Buffer) at 
Borland.Vcl.TDataSet.SetBufListSize(Int32 Value) at  
Borland.Vcl.TDataSet.CloseCursor() at  
Borland.Vcl.TDataSet.SetActive(Boolean Value) at Borland.Vcl.TDataSet.Close()
```

EDIT2: I have put a check in the code to make sure the `selCursor.Active` before selCursor.Close. The stack trace suggests there is nothing to close.

Comment: What is this `Cursor()` thing, please? Since when has it been in Delphi? Can I read about it anywhere online?

Comment: Its a custom function that returns an opened dataset.

Comment: Right, thanks! I did suspect that, but then, don't why, I started thinking it was a new feature in one of the latest versions.

Comment: Any chance to see the source for `Cursor()`? Maybe something's not entirely right in that function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very odd and I still don't know why but it seems that randomly the Cursor is already closed. It seems that adding:

```
if (selCursor.Active) then
    selCursor.Close;
```

has sorted the issue ...

Thanks for the answers and time spent trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if the Cursor returns an empty Dataset ?

You try to Access the `selCursor.FieldByName ...` without a record, I think.

Comment: It works fine with an empty dataset. FieldByName doesn't try and access an index so its odd.. Please also see my edit to the main post (adding now).

Comment: Still, I would try to use `selCursor.Fields(0).AsInteger` in stead of the `FieldByName`  (without begin able to look at Delphi - cannot start if from where I'm typing now). Just a guess.

Comment: Doing as you have suggested is more likely to cause an error because if the cursor is empty then it won't have a value at index 0. That would then throw an index out of bounds errors ... FieldByName (AFAIK) won't allow that to happen.

Answer (score -1):

```
  selCursor := Cursor(selSQL); //Returns a DataSet from a TADOQuery
```

Maybe problem is here, FieldByName is in exception handler so you have error on next line. You have to check if Cursor() is ok.

Comment: FieldByName isn't in an exception handler and will return an error should the cursor not be valid.